# Panda rolling over a dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with 4 columns and as I roll with a window size of k, Is there a way to ensure that I have all the columns in each rolling window?

```
d = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'y':[5,4,3,2,1],
    'r':[2,3,4,5,6],
    'q':[1,2,8,9,0]
})
# Doing this does not work!!!
d.rolling(window=3,axis=0)
```

For example, I suppose window = 2, I want rolling to return all the x,y,r,q columns for every three window slice

slice #1

```
[1,5,2,1],
[2,4,3,2]
```

slice #2

```
[2,4,3,2],
[3,3,4,8]
```

so on and so forth

Comment: Eventually I need to do some custom data aggregation on each of the rolling slices. But I need all the columns in every slice. Anyone know if it is possible using panda dataframe?

Comment: The rolling function is meant only for aggregations not to return a set of rows.  You might consider creating your own generator